# What are the units of the area method in shapely?

Tags: python, polygon, area, shapely

I would like to know the area of a polygon created with shapely. For example, if I have the polygon, `poly = geometry.Polygon([[0,4], [1,0], [0, 1], [1,1]])`, and I want to know it's area. For that, I'll use the `poly.area` method, but I don't find what the units of the value coming out of that are.

Are there in pixels^2?

The documentation here : https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.area.html does't seem to give the answer.

Comment: Since your input data doesn't have any units, neither does `poly.area`. The area of a 2x2 square is "4"; not "4 pixels" or "4 meters" or anything; just "4". See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80881/what-is-unit-of-shapely-length-attribute) on [gis.se] for a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your input data **does** have units (pixels, feet, meters...), and area units are simply the square of the input unit.

That's true as long as the input values represent coordinates on a flat surface.

However, latitude and longitude are often used as input values. In this case, the resulting area doesn't represent an area on a flat surface, so it's useless for most practical applications.